# Nested function in Python class

Tags: python-3.x, oop

i have a little "basic understanding" Python problem.
So let me explain my problem.
At first a very simple code snippet.

```python
class Revert:
    __sentence = ""

    def __init__(self, sentence: str):
        self.__sentence = sentence

    def get_sentence(self):
        return self.__sentence

    def revert_sentence(self):
        return self.__sentence[::-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Revert("Stackoverflow").get_sentence())
    print(Revert("Stackoverflow").revert_sentence())
```

So this show normal function calling of python functions.
But how can i transform this code so i can call the revert function like this:

```python
    print(Revert("Stackoverflow").get_sentence().revert_sentence())
```

Maybe I'm miss the forest through the trees. But I didn't get it how to do this.
I already tried to solve the problem with `innermethods` but this didn't work for me

```python
...
    def get_sentence(self):
        def revert_sentence():
            self.revert_sentence()

        return self.__sentence
...
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You must understand what an object of a class is. And how you call a function on an object instance. If you want to chain the functions you must return the Object from the first function not a member of the Object(or class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go:

```
class Revert:
    __sentence = ""

    def __init__(self, sentence: str):
        self.__sentence = sentence

    def get_sentence(self):
        return self.__sentence

    def revert_sentence(self):
        # It's important to know that you are making changes in the same instance of the object
        self.__sentence = self.__sentence[::-1]
        return self
    
    def pseudo_revert(self):
        # Return a new object with reverted string, but this instance still has original string intact.
        return Revert(self.__sentence[::-1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    r1 = Revert("Stackoverflow")
    r2 = Revert("Stackoverflow")

    print(r1.get_sentence()) # Stackoverflow
    print(r1.revert_sentence().get_sentence()) # wolfrevokcatS
    print(r1.get_sentence()) # wolfrevokcatS
    
    print(r2.get_sentence()) # Stackoverflow
    print(r2.pseudo_revert().get_sentence()) # wolfrevokcatS
    print(r2.get_sentence()) # Stackoverflow
```

Hope this helps you understand the object, instance of an object, and method of object distinctly.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `__str__` to return the actual string. Then in the existing methods, return the object. This way you can chain. But when `print` is applied to it, that `__str__` method will kick in:

```
class Revert:
    __sentence = ""

    def __init__(self, sentence: str):
        self.__sentence = sentence

    def get_sentence(self):
        return self

    def revert_sentence(self):
        return Revert(self.__sentence[::-1])

    # Some more such methods ...
    def upper(self):
        return Revert(self.__sentence.upper())

    def first(self, count):
        return Revert(self.__sentence[:count])

    def dotted(self):
        return Revert(".".join(self.__sentence))

    # For getting a string
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__sentence


print(Revert("Stackoverflow").get_sentence().revert_sentence())

print(Revert("Stackoverflow")
         .revert_sentence()
         .first(8)
         .upper()
         .revert_sentence()
         .first(4)
         .dotted())   # "O.V.E.R"
```

Note that now the `.get_sentence()` method is not really doing much, and you can always strip it from a chain.

Comment: This is more a comment for Mo7art than for you, but it doesn't really make sense to have a member function that just returns the object. You _already_ need to have the object before you call `.get_sentence()`. Maybe this is a simplified example for Stack Overflow, and the actual `.get_sentence()` actually operates on the `self` object and returns the result, which would make more sense.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes this was a very simplified code sample, in the original code I do something in the here called `.get_sentence()` function.
Also, there should be many of the kind of functions like `get_sentence()` would that work there too ?
@trincot The problem is, that I didn't call the print method (only here in the example). I would like to work with the returned Object in other functions.

Comment: Sure, more functions would work too. I added a few more to my answer.